# Wordpress post count issue

Tags: wordpress

In Post listing ( logged in as administrator), I am getting a list of posts (21 items) and the filters above listing shows All (121) | Published (121).  If I click on any of those filters ( All or Published ) the list remain unchanged.

Means the system says there 121 published items, however only 21 shows in listing.  Only these 21 items are showing in front end also.

I ran the following query in my database

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_type` =  'post' AND post_status =  'publish'
```

It shows 89 records.

One thing I found is, for the item which are actually getting listed has the following extra post meta values

- _edit_last
- _edit_lock
- _thumbnail_id

I can edit the items which are not listed by manually changing the url value (post.php?post=xxx&action=edit).  However if I visit the permalink of the same it shows wordpress Page not found page.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is one plugin which is in fact not shown up under the plugin sections, however it was actually exist in the plugins folder.  I removed the plugin and it worked.